# TFS 2017 CI - not triggering

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

I did some maintenance today in the agent folders and now continuous integration is no longer working.  I removed the agents (2 of them), removed the directories, reinstalled the agents, repeat x2, rebooted both the TFS controller and build machine, but yet nothing.

Does anybody know where some logs are that can help?  To trigger the builds I am editing a file in a directory that is monitored by many build definitions.

Any suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: Which build are you using XAML or vNext build? Try to find **Event View** on the build agent machine if there are some useful info for troubleshooting.  Also try to restart  **Visual Studio Team Foundation Background Job Agent service**  on TFS sever and corresponding agent service (VSOagentXX) on the build agent machine.

Comment: vNext builds.  I have removed / reinstalled the agents many times, rebooted both build + controller many times, deleted pools, added new ones, new agents, no luck.  I do see errors in the controller event viewer - 404's when connecting to _api directories in the site.  

404 Not Found. Requested Url: http://ServerNameRemoved:8080/tfs/_apis/connectionData?connectOptions=IncludeServices&lastChangeId=-1&lastChangeId64=-1


Up next is a repair of TFS.

Comment: If change the URL to below success.
http://ServerNameRemoved/_apis/connectionData?connectOptions=IncludeServices&lastChangeId=-1&lastChangeId64=-1

Comment: Thanks for the sharing ,did your issue fixed? your url is not clear , you could use `http:xxx` this format to show the url, which will display more clearly

Comment: I figured it out- I believe the root cause of this is I am using the build definition to do double duty - it does CI (hardcoded to our TIP) and dynamic pathing in the repository (for scheduled and past build paths).  This was supposed to be fixed in Version 15.117.26714.0, but it appears there may be some bugs still.

Comment: I was able to recreate on a small controlled scale.  A ticket was opened here - https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/101267/dynamic-repository-path-breaks-ci.html